# Get what areas have more than three qualified employees

Tags: mysql

I have this tables from the MySql database i'm working with:

```
create table employees (
    num_pass int(5) not null,
    name varchar(40),
    primary key (num_pass)
    )engine=innodb;

create table laboratories (
    code int(10) not null,
    name varchar(40),
    primary key (codi),
)engine=innodb;

create table areas (
    code int(5) not null,
    codeLab int(10) not null,
    level enum('H','M','L'),
    primary key (code, codeLab),
    foreign key (codeLab) references laboratories(code)
    )engine=innodb;

create table qualifieds (
    num_pass int(5) not null,
    area_assigned int(5),
    lab int(5),
    primary key (num_pass),
    foreign key (num_pass) references employees(num_pass),
    foreign key (area_assigned, lab) references areas (code, codeLab)
    )engine=innodb;
```

Now i want to get what areas have more than three qualified employees. Specifically, i want to get area code along with the name of the laboratory, laboratory and ordered by region.

I tried to use this command in order to get the code of the area

```
select b.code 
from employees e, areas b, qualifieds q 
where e.num_pass=q.num_pass 
and 3 < (select count(b1.code) 
         from areas b1, qualifieds q1, employers e1 
         where e1.num_pass=q1.num_pass
         and q1.area_assigned=b1.code 
         and q1.lab=b1.codeLab);
```

But all what i get is a list of all the area codes repeated as many times as the number of employees (i have areas with code 1,2,3,4 and 6 employees, what i get is the sequence 1,2,3,4 repeated 6 times).Any idea about how to get the information i need?

Comment: Two out of three is good, but see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY and HAVING to find a group with more than 3 records...

```
select areas_assigned, lab, count(num_pass)
    from qualifieds
    group by areas_assigned, lab
    having count(num_pass)>3;
```

If you then need to expand on this, then add joins...

```
select q.areas_assigned, l.name, count(q.num_pass)
    join laboratories l on l.lab = q.lab
    from qualifieds q
    group by q.areas_assigned, l.name
    having count(q.num_pass)>3;
```

Comment: I changed something, but your answer gave me the correct input, i put:
`select distinct a.code, l.name
from qualifieds q, laboratories l, areas a
group by q.area_assigned, q.lab
having count(q.num_pass)>3;`
And now it works, thank you!